# How can I display this.state value in the Text tag?

Tags: react-native

I'm about to mark this.state in the Text tag. But the code I wrote does not show the value. What is the problem and how can I display it?
And i want this.state value change

```
    constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state= {
      nickname: ""
    }
  }
  componentWillMount(){
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user =>{
      firebase.database()
      .ref('/users/' + user.uid)
      .once('value', function(snapshot){
        console.log("snapshot value = "+snapshot.val().nickname)
        var nickname = snapshot.val().nickname
        console.log(nickname)

      })
      .then(
          this.state.nickname = snapshot.val().nickname
      )

    })
  }
```

Comment: Who knows :) Can you share your code so we can have a look? Or better yet, create a [minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and post that. Nobody is going to spend hours digging through hundreds of lines of code, so if you can reduce the problem to a small example that demonstrates the same problem, that would help everyone. If not, then creating the small example and seeing it work will likely help you debug the problem in your project on your own. It's a great exercise **and** a time-saver!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you try this?

```
 componentWillMount(){
        firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user =>{
          firebase.database()
          .ref('/users/' + user.uid)
          .once('value', function(snapshot){
          })
          .then(rtnick => {
              this.setState({ nickname:rtnick.val().nickname });
              console.log(nickname);
          })

        })
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

first of all, you have to update the `state` the proper way using `this.setState({})` function, and then in order to show it in you `<Text>` component you only need to pass the state that you need:

```
state= {
  nickname: ""
}

componentWillMount() {
  firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
    firebase.database()
      .ref('/users/' + user.uid)
      .once('value', function(snapshot) {
        console.log("snapshot value = "+snapshot.val().nickname)
        let nickname = snapshot.val().nickname
        console.log(nickname)
      })
      .then(
        this.setState({ nickname: snapshot.val().nickname });
      )
   })
}

render() {
  const { nickname } = this.state;

  return (
    <Text>{nickname}</Text>
  );
}
```

Hopes this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In your render function

```
<Text>{this.state.nickname}</ Text>
```

Edit:

```
componentWillMount(){
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user =>{
      firebase.database()
      .ref('/users/' + user.uid)
      .once('value', function(snapshot){
        console.log("snapshot value = "+snapshot.val().nickname)
        var nickname = snapshot.val().nickname
        console.log(nickname)
        return nickname;
      })
      .then(nickname => {
          this.setState({ nickname });
      })

    })
  }
```

Comment: I'd like to put the value from the firebase into the state, but how do I do that?

Comment: Edit the then function in componentWillMount. I will edit my answer to show it

Comment: this.state.nickname wont edit the value of nickname. You have to use the this.setState function @서성환

Comment: error :
Invariant Violation: Invariant Violation: Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {node_, ref_, index_}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Comment: Can you console log the value of nickname in the then part? And comment it here